# redirect a against different requests (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I am working on laravel 5.3
I want to redirect a user on different pages again from which page user is coming .
I have 3 pages one is

**create**

**view all**

**view**

I am using create page for create and edit purpose.
view all and view both page have edit button. after click it goes in Controller edit method and redirect to edit page in both cases.

Edit page have a return button. I want when user click on return it should go to view all if he comes from view all page to edit other wise if he came form view it should go back to view when he click on return.

Code for edit button is as in both view and view all pages is as

```
    <li>
      <a href="{{ route('student.edit', $student->id) }}"> Edit</a>
    </li>
```

on click edit it comes here in controller edit method

```
public function edit($id){
    $student = Student::findOrFail($id);
    $data = ['action' => 'edit'];

    return view('student.create')->with(compact('data', 'student'));
 }
```

Buttons on create page are as right now

```
<div class="row">
  <button type="submit" value="dd">Save and add</button>
  @if ($data['action'] == 'edit')
  <a href="{{ route('student.index') }}">
     <button type="button">Return</button>
  </a>
  <button type="submit" value="edit">Save</button>
  @endif
</div>
```

Now its returning me to view all students fine from update method because i use check there on button value as

```
if(Input::get('add')) {
   return redirect()->route('student.create');
}else{
   return redirect()->route('student.index');
}
```

How can i redirect to student.view on base of that user cam from student view to edit

Any idea how can i do it may be i also can work with session please help how to do

Comment: Use laravel's helper method `back()`. It will generate the url of previous page for you.

Comment: it should go back when i click return button

Comment: on click return button its not go in update method just should return back from edit page

Comment: `<a href="{{ route('student.index') }}"><button type="button" Return</button></a>`
From here above route it should go back

Comment: Yes....it will definitely go to the last page from where the user came.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `URI` on the request using `$uri = $request->path();` then use a `switch` the checks against `$uri` to dictate what to do next.

You will also need to modify your controllers head with

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

and update the edit method to `public function edit(Request $request, $id){`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#request-path-and-method

Comment: dear url will be same for both because both have edit route

Comment: <a href="{{ route('student.index') }}"><button type="button" Return</button></a> From here above route it should go back .Its not goes in controller on return click

Answer (score 0):

To return to the previous page/route in your controller use:

```
return redirect()->back();
```

Or simple:

```
return back();
```

Then you can have edit function like this:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $student = Student::findOrFail($id);
    $data = [ 'action' => 'edit'];

    return back()->with(compact('data', 'student'));
}
```

Ref: [Laravel 5.2 doc - redirect](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirects)

**UPDATES:**

If you mean it should go back after clicking the Return button then this should be enough:

```
 <a href="{{ URL::previous() }}"> Return </a>
```

> PS: I tested this on Laravel 5.2.* and it worked
>   I hope this helps :)

Comment: it should go back after click on return button

Comment: It should go back after executing the function

Comment: <a href="{{ route('student.index') }}"><button type="button" Return</button></a> From here above route it should go back .Its not goes in controller on return click

Comment: yes its working for return but still problem is that i also have a add button if he 1st add and the clicks return its not return on that page where required???

Comment: When the student adds a new record normally, where does it go? it stays on the page or it goes to the view page? if it goes to the view page then the `back()` function in your controller method will do the job for you. You should try that and tell us if its still not working....

Comment: after adding record there 2 buttons addmore and 2nd is return if user clicks addmore its goes in update method and again gives form to create more if he click return its not goes in update it should redirect back

Comment: it can be in one way if i change route mean not similar for both please help how can i send an optional parameter with  route and get in edit method ? then with this parameter i will set a session value which will i get in create page

Comment: now i am also able to send parameter with route as 
<a href="{{ route('student.edit', $student->id) }}/?view"> 

How can i get this  parameter above as view in my edit method???

Comment: with your present edit function, the path parameter you already passed will be the `$id` argument. In order to be sure, just return the `$id` in your controller method then see if it is, if not then in your routes you have to set this as part of the url e.g `Route::post('/edit/{studentId}', ....`. By the way this is leading to another question. I suggest you check Stackoverflow well you will find other answers...

Answer (score 0):

Use {{ URL::previous() }}

you can update your code like below

```
<a href="{{ URL::previous() }}"><button type="button">Return</button></a>
```

Comment: yes its working for return but still problem is that i also have a add button if he 1st add and the clicks return its not return on that page where required???

Comment: On create page you are not showing return link. when you click on edit, view all page edit and view page edit then only you are showing return url. then where is the problem.